# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined. How do I solve this?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to follow the tutorial here - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

But I keep getting the following error when I'm trying to build my extension:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I have "permissions": ["storage"] included

Comment: Possibly a typo, or not reloading the extension after making changes. You need to include the code that raises that error, and where it is located.

Comment: For me, I needed to clear list of errors (because chrome is not deleting them after reload)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this today. It seems if you get an error, it's not cleared even if you reload the extension - you have to explicitly clear the error seperately.

In chrome://extensions/ clicking on the extension in questions "Errors" button and then the "Clear all" button fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

If the error does not disappear after you have declared "storage" in the manifest, and also reloaded the extension. In this case, uninstall the extension and install it again. The error will disappear.
Browsers are also buggy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're attempting to access the chrome.storage API from the console, you must select the chrome extension (like shown below). Hope it's any help.

[image: Chrome Console extension context]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Reload your extension in the extension Manager. Check the picture bellow:

[image]